# Modified presentation of the Clifford algebra (II)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I modify the presentation of the Clifford algebra with an orthogonal symmetry $S, S^2=1, S^*=S$, taking the free algebra with the following relations:
$$
S(e) \otimes f + S(f) \otimes e = -2 g(e,f)
$$
There are two Dirac operators ${\cal D}, S({\cal D})$ such that I have the Lichnerowicz type formulas:
$$
S({\cal D})\circ {\cal D}= {\cal D}\circ S({\cal D})=-\Delta + \frac {r(S)}{4}
$$
with $r(S)$, the modified scalar curvature. Is there an interpretation with supersymmetries?